# How the Memory Page size is set for a controller

Tags: microcontroller, cortex-m

When using a controller, is it the architecture of the controller deciding the page size or is it configurable? The very specific example that i have is an STM32L151 series which uses Cortex M3 architecture. So in this particular case is it decided by cortex m3 or the initialization code?

Comment: The Cortex-M doesn't have virtual memory, so there are no pages. (Actually the flash memory is organized in pages for programming, but I don't think you are talking about those.)

Comment: please be more specific, what kind of pages?

Comment: I have a requirement to find the time required for writing onto flash in STM32L1 series controller. Going through the data sheet, I get the detail that:       "Programming / erasing
time for byte / word /
double word / half-page"    so here i believe the time required for programming and erasing byte, word, dword and half page are the same. So I need to know how much bytes a half page is on STM32L1 controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page size of the flash memory is determined by the microcontroller hardware and cannot be configured in software.  The documentation for your microcontroller should specify it somewhere.

You should look in ST's programming manuals and datasheets.

Comment: So is the flash page size same across all controllers of the same architecture, or is this architecture independent..?

Comment: If by architecture you mean Cortex M3, then no.  It will tend to be the same in similar families of chips made by the same manufacturer, like say the STM32F103 family.